# Python abort initializing without interrupting the run

Tags: python, initialization

I want to initialize objects with every of the rows of a dataframe. However, jth row should be skipped if dataframe.ix[j,'A']==0. So the code should look like:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init___(self,row):
        if (row['A']==0):
            (quit initializing without giving error message)
        else:
            self.a = row['A']
```

It is easy to do if I filter the rows out before calling init. But I feel the filtering should be one of the features of class foo. Suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `return` ?

Comment: This is what classmethods are for.

Comment: @DainDwarf: That won't abort initialization, merely short-circuit it.

Comment: I thought that's what you expected. What do you exactly need, from that caller point of view? If I do `myobj = foo(badData)`, what do you expect `myobj` to be?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks a lot! I am going to take a look. Definitely good to know.

Comment: @DainDwarf: And that's why the asker needs to try a completely different approach.

Comment: @DainDwarf, I expect foo(badData) never be created. If I use return, it will still be an empty object.

Comment: How about raising Exception when receive bad Data. But provide a classmethod, this method will accept dataframe, filter rows, and returns all valid foo objects